# parsing in python

Tags: python

I have following string

adId:4028cb901dd9720a011e1160afbc01a3;siteId:8a8ee4f720e6beb70120e6d8e08b0002;userId:5082a05c-015e-4266-9874-5dc6262da3e0

I need only the value of adId,siteId and userId.
means

4028cb901dd9720a011e1160afbc01a3

8a8ee4f720e6beb70120e6d8e08b0002

5082a05c-015e-4266-9874-5dc6262da3e0

all the 3 in different variable or in a array so that i can use all three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
input='adId:4028cb901dd9720a011e1160afbc01a3;siteId:8a8ee4f720e6beb70120e6d8e08b0002;userId:5082a05c-015e-4266-9874-5dc6262da3e0'

result={}
for pair in input.split(';'):
    (key,value) = pair.split(':')
    result[key] = value

print result['adId']
print result['siteId']
print result['userId']
```

Answer (score 18):

You can split them to a dictionary if you don't need any fancy parsing:

```
In [2]: dict(kvpair.split(':') for kvpair in s.split(';'))
Out[2]:
{'adId': '4028cb901dd9720a011e1160afbc01a3',
 'siteId': '8a8ee4f720e6beb70120e6d8e08b0002',
 'userId': '5082a05c-015e-4266-9874-5dc6262da3e0'}
```

Comment: It's a copy paste from ipython interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
matches = re.findall("([a-z0-9A-Z_]+):([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+);", buf)

for m in matches:
    #m[1] is adid and things
    #m[2] is the long string.
```

You can also limit the lengths using {32} like

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+){32};
```

Regular expressions allow you to **validate** the string and split it into component parts.

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome method called [split()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions) for python that will work nicely for you. I would suggest using it twice, once for ';' then again for each one of those using ':'.